# sudo: unable to resolve host legend27

Tags: localhost

I am new to this and need help I got this error and need step by step instructions

sudo: unable to resolve host legend27

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: legend27@legend27:~$  /etc/hostname
bash: /etc/hostname: Permission denied    i get this error also.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Please update your question with output of `hostnamectl`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have your hostname entry present in `/etc/hosts` like this?

```
127.0.0.1  legend27
```

And BTW, `/etc/hostname` is a file which needs to be edited, not a command to be executed.

```
$ /etc/hostname # Executes /etc/hostname as a command; wrong way to do it
$ gedit /etc/hostname # Opens /etc/hostname for editing, right way to do it
```

You get that "Permission denied" error because `/etc/hostname` doesn't have the execute bit set on its file permissions, and it is not intended to be executed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody advises to modify `/etc/hosts`. But in some cases this may not be possible (for example inside a docker container). So, I had to find a better way and I came up with this:

```
echo "alias sudo='sudo -h 127.0.0.1'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
source ~/.bashrc
```

Aliases don't work in bash scripts, but we can use variables: `sudo='sudo -h 127.0.0.1'`